# Nifi Error in putHDFS processor : Unable to determine current user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sftp, apache-nifi

Im trying to put files from SFTP into HDFS using Nifi, im using ListSFTP >> FetchSFTP >> PutHDFS Processors.
Data is flowing till putHDFS.

I have configured putHDFS with required hadoop conf files like [/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml,/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml]

I dont have a kerberos key. Receiving the following error.

*'Component' is invalid because failed to perform validation due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to determine current user*

Comment: You'll need to get the full stacktrace from nifi-app.log and add it to the question

Comment: I cannot see any log in the file. I tried running separately. This error comes before even we run the job.

Comment: @BryanBende thanks a lot for the response. got to know the user in which the nifi is configured is not having access to hive and hdfs cluster

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Bryan, After configuring the Nifi user to have access to Hadoop cluster solved the issue. Though this is a compile time error couldn't see anything in logs.

This fixed the issue after restarting Nifi :)